# Springboot Rest(ful) Api and lookup values

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I want to write some Rest(ful) application with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA.

Let's assume that for business reasons I have a database with the following tables:

```
customer(id number, first_name text, last_name text, type text);
customer_type(type text, description text);
```

where:

- `id` is generated by the database at inserion time
- `type` column in `customer` table is a foreign key to `type` column in `customer_type` table and it is immutable from a microservice point of view, just a lookup table.

Assuming I want to create APIs for CRUD operations on a customer but want to minimize api calls when just reading, I suppose I need the following operations:

- GET /customer/{id}
- POST /customer
- PUT /customer/{id}
- DELETE /customer/{id}

How the body should be structured?
For GET operation the response should be

```
{
   "id":123,
   "firstName":"John",
   "lastName":"Doe",
   "customerType":{
      "type":"P",
      "description":"Premium Customer"
   }
}
```

But for POST I imagine I need to avoid sending the id and send just the customer type since the description is immutable and the client needs the description only for visualizing the information on screen, but this leads to different request body from the one returned in the GET operation.

For the PUT operation is the same but also should the `id` field be sent? How to handle the case where the id in the API path is different from the id in the request body if sent?

DELETE should not be a problem since it just deletes the row in `customer` table.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> How the body should be structured?

Let's make a step back first and let us discuss quickly what you basically try when following a REST architecture and why and how REST installs those mechanisms.

REST is an architectural style that helps in decoupling clients from servers by introducing indirection mechanisms which may seem odd at first but in the end allow you to achieve the required level of decoupling which allows clients to introduce changes which clients will naturally adept to. Such indirection mechanisms include attaching URIs to link-relation names, using form-based representation formats to tell a client how to create requests, content-type negotiation to return representations supported and understood by others and so forth. If you don't need such properties, i.e. as client and servers always go hand in hand in regards to changes and communicate on predefined messages, REST is probably not the best style to follow. If you though have a server that is contacted by various clients not under your control or a client that has to contact various servers, also not under your direct control, this is where REST truly starts to shine if all parties adhere to these concepts.

One of RESTs premise is that a server will teach clients everything they need to know in order to construct requests. If you look at the Web, where HTML is basically used everywhere, you might see that HTML defines [HTML forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) which basically allow a server to explain to a client what properties of a resource the server expects as input. On top of that the form also tells you client which HTTP operation to use, which target URI to send the request to and which media-type to represent the state in. In HTML this is usually implicitly given as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which chains properties together i.e. like this:

```
firstName=Roman&lastName=Vottner&role=Dev
```

or the like. This is in essence what HATEOAS or `hypertext as the engine of application state` is all about. You use in-build controls of the media-type exchanged to allow your client to progress its task instead of having to consult external documentation to lookup the "API" of some services. I.e. a form could state that an input only allows numeric values, that a sub-portion of the form represents a date/time picker widget which a client could render to a user accordingly, or an element represents a slider with a given range of admissible values and the like.

How the actual representation format you have to send to the server has to look like depends on the instructed media-type. I.e. [HAL forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/) uses `application/json` by default and also specifies that `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` needs to be supported. Other media-types have explicitly negotiated between client and server. [Ion](https://ionspec.org/#forms) states that `application/json` or `application/ion+json` have to be negotiated via the `Content-Type` request header.

In plain `application/json` the url-encoded payload from above could simply be expressed as:

```json
{
    "firstName": "Roman",
    "lastName": "Vottner",
    "role": "Dev"
}
```

and this is OK as the server basically instructed you to send this data in that format.

There are further media-types available that are worth a closer look whether they could fit your need or not. I.e. [Hydra](https://www.hydra-cg.com/spec/latest/core/#documenting-a-web-api) has a bit of a different take on this matter by connecting Linked Data to REST and its affordances called operations and allows to describe resources and its properties through LD classes. So the presence of an affordance for a certain resource tells you what you can do with that resource, like i.e. updating its state, and therefore also which class it belongs to and therefore which properties it has.

This just should illustrate how a negotiated media type finally decides how the actual representation needs to look like that has to be sent to the server.

In regards of whether to put in resource identifiers in the payload or not it depends. Usually resources are identified by the URI/IRI and this, as a whole, is the identifier of the resource. In your application though you will reference related domain objects through their ID which does not necessarily need to be, and probably also should not be, part of the IRI itself. I.e. let's assume we retrieve a resource that represents an order. That order contains the users name and address, the various items that got ordered including some meta data describing those items and what not. It usually makes sense in such a case to add the orderId which you use in your application even though the URI may contain that information already. Users of that API are usually not interested in those URIs but the actual content and might also never see those URIs if they are hidden behind automated processes or user interfaces. If a user now wants to print out that order s/he has all the information needed to file complaints later on via phone i.e. In other cases, i.e. if you design a resource to be an all-purpose clipboard like, copy&paste location, an ID does not make any sense unless you grant the user to explicitly reference one of that states directly.

The reason why IDs should not be part of the URI itself stems from the fact that a URI shouldn't change if the actual resource does not change. I.e. we have a customer who went through a merge a couple of years ago. They used to expose all their products via own URIs that exposed the productId as part of the URI. During the merger the tried to combine the various different data models to reduce the number of systems they had to operate while serving each of their customers with the same data as before as the underlying products didn't change. As they tried to stay "backwards" compatible for the purpose of supporting legacy systems of their customers, they quickly noticed that exposing those productIds as part of the URI was causing them some troubles. If they had used a mapping table of i.e. exposed UUIDs to internal productIds (again an introduction of indirection) earlier they could have reduced their whole data model and thus complexity by a lot while being able to change the mapping from internal prodcutId to UUID on the fly while allowing their clients to lookup the product information.

Long story short, as hopefully can be seen the structure of a representation depends on the exchanged media type. There are loads of different [media-types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) available. Use the ones that allow you to describe resources to clients, such as HAL/HAL forms, Ion, Hydra, .... In regards to URIs, don't overengineer URIs. They are, as a whole, just a pointer to a resource and clients are usually interested in the content, not the URI! As such, make use of indirection-features like link-relation names, content-type negotiation and so forth to help remove the direct coupling of clients to services but instead rely more on the document type exchanged. The media-type here becomes basically the contract of the message. Through mappings on the client and server side resources of various representations can be "translated" to an object which you can use in your application.

As you've tagged your question with [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot) and [spring-data-jpa](/questions/tagged/spring-data-jpa), you might want to look into [spring-hateoas](https://spring.io/projects/spring-hateoas). It supports HAL out of the box, HAL forms can be used via affordances though the media-type needs to be enabled explicitly for it otherwise you might miss out on the form-template in the responses. Hydra support in `spring-hateoas` seems to be added through [hydra-java](https://github.com/dschulten/hydra-java) which implements the Spring HATEOAS SPI. While [Amazon](https://amzn.github.io/ion-docs/) provides implementation for Ion for various programming languages, including Java, it does not yet support Spring HATEOAS or Spring in general. Here a custom SPI implementation may be necessary.

Comment: This is a great explanation regarding Rest and more in general content negotiation but I'm tied (business reasons, I'm just a dev) to using application/json, lookup tables are out of my control and for some purposes i need to identify a resource in a unique way, in the example of customer I don't have such unique id in the data so I need to generate one on each new customer. This id is then needed to the clients to uniquely use data regarding that resource, from getting it to modyfing it.

My question was more centered on what are the best practices regarding this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For PUT operations you need to send the id of the entity that you want to update.

If you want to generate the same response as you would get in GET, then you need to write a DTO and map details accordingly.